# Why translation is the null vector of essential matrix

Tags: computer-vision, geometry

In computer vision, if `E` is the essential matrix, and `T` is the translation, then

`transpose(E)*T = 0. // or E*T=0, depending on how you define E`

seems to be a known result. Why is it the case? what is the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before speaking about the intuition behind this, first let's answer that question from a symbolic point of view. The essential matrix is often defined as

```
E=R*[T]_x
```

where `R` is the relative rotation between the two cameras, `T` is the translation, and `[.]_x` denotes the matrix of the cross product with `T`. Now, it is clear that

`E*T=R*[T]_x*T=0 //because the cross product of T with itself is null`

Now, we know that the Essential matrix has rank `2`. According to the rank theorem, this means that the kernel of E is of dimension `1`. So the nullspace of `E` is just the space defined by `alpha*T`, where `alpha` is a real number.

---

Now, let's discuss the intuition. I suggest you draw a little figure on paper to make this easier to visualize. Let us note the two camera centers `C_1` and `C_2`. Also, let us note `z` a 3d point expressed in the coordinate frame of `C_2`, and let `y` be another 3d point that is expressed relative to the coordinate frame of `C_1`. First, let's ask ourselves what the Essential matrix does, *i.e.* what does the equation `y^t*E*z` mean. Now, consider the plane `L` defined by the three points `C_1,C_2,z`. To make things easier, let's first see the case where `R==Identiy`. In that situation,

```
y^t E * z= y^t * [T]_x * z
```

and here, `[T]_x * z` gives you the normal vector of the plane `L`, since `[T]_x` is nothing more than `C_2-C_1` (or `C_1-C_2`, doesn't really matter for our purposes). Now that you know that the normal vector of `L` is `[T]_x * z`, you can see that what `y^t * [T]_x *z` does is *check the extent to which* `y` *lies inside* `L` (how do you check if a point lies in a plane? You see if the dot product with the plane normal is zero, and that is what this code does.).

Now, what if `R` is not the Identity? Notice that the normal of `L` that you obtain with `[T]_x * z` is expressed with respect to the coordinate frame of `C_2`. The multiplication by `R` transforms this vector and expresses it in the referential of `C_1`. Now that `y` and the normal are in the same coordinate frame, you can check "how much" `y` lies inside `L`.

---

Finally, let's go back to developing and intuition about why `T` is the nullspace of `E`, we can just see that the normal of `L` is just `0`. So, this is a degenerate plane, and any point `w` in 3d Euclidian space lies on it, because `w\t*0=0`.